# Erro código de barras da impressora zebra

Tags: impressora

Ao imprimir na impressora zebra RW 420 utilizando linguagem EPL, o código de barras é exibido com uma tarja preta no meio, como se as barras estivessem emendadas (ver imagem).

Porém, utilizando o mesmo código, a impressão é feita normalmente (sem a tarja preta) com a impressora *Datamax*.

Já tentei ajustar a densidade no código EPL, mas não resolveu.

[image: Erro no código de barras (tarja preta)]

Segue o código em EPL:

```
N
I8,A,001


Q0001,0
q860
rN
S2
D4
ZT
JF
O
R0,0
f100
X0,10,4,686,115
A7,17,0,2,1,1,N,\"RECEBEMOS DA \"
A7,41,0,2,1,1,N,\"NOME DO FORNECEDOR\"
A7,65,0,2,1,1,N,\"OS PRODUTOS E/OU SERVICOS CONSTANTES DA NF-e\"
A7,89,0,2,1,1,N,\"INDICADA AO LADO\"
X690,10,4,825,115
A697,17,0,2,1,1,N,\"NF-e\"
A697,41,0,2,1,1,N,\"N. 9999\"
A697,65,0,2,1,1,N,\"Serie 118\"
X0,119,4,825,179
LO350,119,2,58
LO600,119,2,58
A7,126,0,2,1,1,N,\"VENDEDOR\"
A7,150,0,2,1,1,N,\"DANIEL PORT\"
A357,126,0,2,1,1,N,\"VALOR TOTAL DA NF-e\"
A357,150,0,2,1,1,N,\"66,54\"
A607,126,0,2,1,1,N,\"DATA DE EMISSAO\"
A607,150,0,2,1,1,N,\"04/03/2016\"
X0,183,4,825,243
LO410,183,2,58
A7,190,0,2,1,1,N,\"Cliente\"
A7,214,0,2,1,1,N,\"111111-NOME DO CLIENTE\"
A417,190,0,2,1,1,N,\"Condicao de pagamento\"
A417,214,0,2,1,1,N,\"VENDA 7 DIAS BOLETO\"
X0,247,4,825,345
A7,254,0,2,1,1,N,\"Observacao\"
A7,278,0,2,1,1,N,\"Declaro que recebi ou ja possuo a tabela informativa de precos de c\"
A7,299,0,2,1,1,N,\"igarros vigente, de acordo com §3° do art. 7/ do IN/RFB n/ 1.204 de\"
A7,320,0,2,1,1,N,\" 24 de outubro de 2011.\"
X0,349,4,825,449
A7,356,0,3,1,1,N,\"DATA DE RECEBIMENTO\"
A394,356,0,3,1,1,N,\"CARIMBO/ASSINATURA\"
LO7,429,50,3
A69,415,0,3,1,1,N,\"/\"
LO92,429,50,3
A144,415,0,3,1,1,N,\"/\"
LO160,429,105,3
LO390,429,400,3
A0,479,0,1,1,1,N,\"Recorte aqui\"
A0,493,0,1,1,1,N,\"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\"
A290,552,0,2,1,1,N,\"DOCUMENTO AUXILIAR DA\"
A283,573,0,2,1,1,N,\"NOTA FISCAL ELETRONICA\"
A700,531,0,2,1,1,N,\"1 - SAIDA\"
A700,552,0,2,1,1,N,\"NF: 9999\"
A700,573,0,2,1,1,N,\"SERIE: 118\"
B135,596,0,1C,2,4,70,N,\"4316 0307 3335 9700 0135 5511 8000 0095 4855 1020 2574\"
X0,676,4,825,756
A7,683,0,2,1,1,N,\"CHAVE DE ACESSO\"
A7,707,0,3,1,1,N,\"4316 0307 3335 9700 0135 5511 8000 0095 4855 1020 2574\"
B180,766,0,1C,2,4,70,N,\"435970898740001070000000000665421047\"
X0,846,4,825,926
A7,853,0,2,1,1,N,\"DADOS DA NF-e\"
A7,877,0,3,1,1,N,\"435970898740001070000000000665421047\"
X0,936,4,825,971
A7,943,0,2,1,1,N,\"NAT OPERACAO: Venda merc adq terc fora estab\"
X0,981,4,825,1131
A8,988,0,2,1,1,N,\"EMITENTE\"
A8,1010,0,2,1,1,N,\"NOME DO FORNECEDOR\"
A8,1032,0,2,1,1,N,\"RUA XXXX, 2222 - \"
A8,1054,0,2,1,1,N,\"CIDADE - XX\"
A8,1076,0,2,1,1,N,\"CEP: 00000000\"
A300,1076,0,2,1,1,N,\"Tel: 34  00000000\"
A8,1098,0,2,1,1,N,\"CNPJ: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"
A300,1098,0,2,1,1,N,\"IE: XXXXXXXXXX\"
A500,1098,0,2,1,1,N,\"IE do ST: \"
A600,1098,0,2,1,1,N,\"\"
X0,1141,4,825,1291
A8,1148,0,2,1,1,N,\"DESTINATARIO\"
A8,1170,0,2,1,1,N,\"111111-NOME DO CLIENTE\"
A8,1192,0,2,1,1,N,\"AV TESTE, 333 - \"
A8,1214,0,2,1,1,N,\"CIDADE - ZZ\"
A8,1236,0,2,1,1,N,\"CEP: 99999999\"
A300,1236,0,2,1,1,N,\"Tel: 34 00000000\"
A8,1258,0,2,1,1,N,\"CNPJ: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"
A300,1258,0,2,1,1,N,\"IE: XXXXXXXXXX\"
X675,1141,4,825,1193
A682,1148,0,2,1,1,N,\"DT EMISSAO\"
A682,1168,0,2,1,1,N,\"04/03/2016\"
X675,1190,4,825,1242
A682,1197,0,2,1,1,N,\"DT SAIDA\"
A682,1217,0,2,1,1,N,\"04/03/2016\"
X675,1239,4,825,1291
A682,1246,0,2,1,1,N,\"HR SAIDA\"
A682,1266,0,2,1,1,N,\"10:05:56\"
A8,1313,0,2,1,1,N,\"DADOS FINANCEIROS\"
X0,1331,4,825,1361
X0,1331,4,825,1361
A7,1338,0,1,1,1,N,\"Valor: R$66,54\"
A280,1338,0,1,1,1,N,\"Vencimento: 11/03/2016\"
A172,1376,0,3,1,1,N,\"DANFE simplificado em contingencia\"
A100,1401,0,3,1,1,N,\"Impresso em decorrencia de problemas tecnicos\"
A7,1435,0,2,1,1,N,\"DADOS DOS PRODUTOS\"
X0,1455,4,825,1527
LO0,1480,825,1
LO113,1455,2,70
LO398,1455,2,70
LO443,1455,2,70
LO503,1455,2,70
LO538,1455,2,70
LO618,1455,2,70
LO712,1455,2,70
A7,1462,0,2,1,1,N,\"COD\"
A120,1462,0,2,1,1,N,\"PRODUTO\"
A405,1462,0,2,1,1,N,\"CST\"
A450,1462,0,2,1,1,N,\"CFOP\"
A510,1462,0,2,1,1,N,\"UN\"
A545,1462,0,2,1,1,N,\"QTDE\"
A625,1462,0,2,1,1,N,\"VL UNIT\"
A718,1462,0,2,1,1,N,\"TOTAL\"
A7,1487,0,2,1,1,N,\"888888\"
A120,1487,0,2,1,1,N,\"PRODUTO XXXXX\"
A405,1487,0,2,1,1,N,\"060\"
A450,1487,0,2,1,1,N,\"5104\"
A510,1487,0,2,1,1,N,\"MI\"
A545,1487,0,2,1,1,N,\"  0,20\"
A625,1487,0,2,1,1,N,\" 332,68\"
A720,1487,0,2,1,1,N,\"   66,54\"
A7,1537,0,2,1,1,N,\"CALCULO DO IMPOSTO\"
X0,1567,4,825,1675
X0,1567,2,155,1617
A7,1574,0,2,1,1,N,\"B CALC ICMS\"
A7,1594,0,2,1,1,N,\"0\"
X155,1567,2,264,1617
A162,1574,0,2,1,1,N,\"VL ICMS\"
A162,1594,0,2,1,1,N,\"0\"
X264,1567,2,433,1617
A271,1574,0,2,1,1,N,\"B CALC ICMSST\"
A271,1594,0,2,1,1,N,\"\"
X433,1567,2,602,1617
A440,1574,0,2,1,1,N,\"VL ICMS SUBST\"
A440,1594,0,2,1,1,N,\"\"
X602,1567,2,824,1617
A609,1574,0,2,1,1,N,\"VL TOTAL PROD\"
A609,1594,0,2,1,1,N,\"66,54\"
X0,1617,2,110,1675
A7,1624,0,2,1,1,N,\"VL FRETE\"
A7,1644,0,2,1,1,N,\"\"
X110,1617,2,228,1675
A117,1624,0,2,1,1,N,\"VL SEGURO\"
A117,1644,0,2,1,1,N,\"\"
X228,1617,2,288,1675
A235,1624,0,2,1,1,N,\"DESC\"
A235,1644,0,2,1,1,N,\"0,00\"
X288,1617,2,478,1675
A295,1624,0,2,1,1,N,\"OUTRAS DESPESAS\"
A295,1644,0,2,1,1,N,\"0,00\"
X478,1617,2,620,1675
A485,1624,0,2,1,1,N,\"VL. TOT IPI\"
A485,1644,0,2,1,1,N,\"\"
X620,1617,2,825,1675
A627,1624,0,3,1,1,N,\"VL TOT NOTA\"
A627,1646,0,4,1,1,N,\"66,54\"
A7,1685,0,2,1,1,N,\"TRANSPORTADOR / VOLUMES TRANSPORTADOS\"
X0,1705,4,825,1775
X0,1705,2,200,1775
A7,1712,0,2,1,1,N,\"FRETE\"
A7,1734,0,1,1,1,N,\"0-EMITENTE\"
A7,1747,0,1,1,1,N,\"1-DESTINATARIO\"
X170,1712,2,195,1737
A178,1720,0,1,1,1,N,\"0\"
X200,1705,2,280,1775
A207,1712,0,2,1,1,N,\"QUANT\"
A207,1734,0,2,1,1,N,\"0\"
X280,1705,2,405,1775
A287,1712,0,2,1,1,N,\"ESPECIE\"
A287,1732,0,2,1,1,N,\"\"
X405,1705,2,517,1775
A412,1712,0,2,1,1,N,\"PLACA\"
A412,1732,0,2,1,1,N,\"XXXNNNN\"
X517,1705,2,642,1775
A524,1712,0,2,1,1,N,\"P BRUTO\"
A524,1732,0,2,1,1,N,\"0,27\"
X642,1705,2,822,1775
A649,1712,0,2,1,1,N,\"P LIQUIDO\"
A649,1732,0,2,1,1,N,\"0,2566\"
A0,1785,0,2,1,1,N,\"DADOS ADICIONAIS\"
X0,1805,4,825,2022
A7,1812,0,1,1,1,N,\"SENHOR VAREJISTA: favor verificar a exigencia contida na IN SRF 1204 de 24/10/11, \"
A7,1826,0,1,1,1,N,\"no tocante a fixacao e manutencao das tabelas de precos ao consumidor em local\"
A7,1840,0,1,1,1,N,\"visivel.\"
A7,1854,0,1,1,1,N,\"\"
A7,1868,0,1,1,1,N,\"NF-e Remessas: NNNNN-4/XXXXX-4\"
A7,1882,0,1,1,1,N,\"Nro. Itens NF: 1 Nro. Pacotes NF: 1.00\"
A7,1896,0,1,1,1,N,\"\"
A7,1910,0,1,1,1,N,\"REGIME ESPECIAL ATO DECLARATORIO DRP N 2015/113.\"
A7,1924,0,1,1,1,N,\"ICMS retido anteriormente por ST cfe. Apend. II, Secao III, item II, RICMS/RS\"
A7,1938,0,1,1,1,N,\"\"
X0,2037,4,825,2167
A7,2044,0,1,1,1,N,\"RESERVADO AO FISCO\"
A400,2172,0,1,1,1,N,\"Desenvolvido por XXXXX\"
A0,2217,0,1,1,1,N,\".\"
P1
```

Reparem que existem 2 códigos de barras no código:

**B135,596,0,1C,2,4,70,N,\"4316 0307 3335 9700 0135 5511 8000 0095 4855 1020 2574\"**

e

B180,766,0,1C,2,4,70,N,\"435970898740001070000000000665421047\"

Apenas o 1º (destacado em negrito) apresenta o problema da tarja preta.

Comment: Este é um site de perguntas e respostas sobre programação.

Comment: Poste o código para facilitar a ajuda. @jbueno A pergunta é sobre o assunto, EPL é uma linguagem específica de algumas impressoras, ela é utilizada em conjunto com linguagens de programação.

Comment: Bah, bem pontuado @rubStackOverflow. Não tinha percebido **_=)_**

Comment: Pronto! Código inserido na publicação.
Alguém sabe me auxiliar na resolução deste problema?

Comment: Tamara, realmente se parecem 2 barras "encavaladas". A tarja preta no meio me parece simplesmente o fato das barras se sobreporem. Se for isso, seria o caso de colocar o comando de avançar o papel entre uma barra e outra. Pode ser que a outra impressora force a quebra "na marra", por isso o problema não se apresenta. Fica a sugestão de fazer um código mais resumido, só com as barras do problema, para facilitar para você fazer o _debug_. Aí, ao resolver, aplica no principal.

Comment: Obrigada pelo resposta @Bacco! Alguma dica de como é esse "comando de avançar o papel entre uma barra e outra"?

Comment: @Tamara seria o caso de pegar o manual do EPL mesmo, provavelmente vai ser algum "form feed" ou coisa parecida. Preferencialmente deve ter algum comando que você possa dizer quanto avançar numericamente, assim você controla a distância entre as barras com mais precisão. Acho mais rápido você que está com a "mão na massa"  encontrar do que eu, faz tempo que eu não chego perto de uma Zebra. E eu nem teria como testar aqui. O importante é após a impressão da 1a barra, e antes da segunda, inserir esse avanço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problema resolvido!**

O erro ocorria por causa dos espaços contidos no número do código de barras.

Estava assim:

B135,596,0,1C,2,4,70,N,\"4316 0307 3335 9700 0135 5511 8000 0095 4855 1020 2574\"

O correto é assim:

B135,596,0,1C,2,4,70,N,\"43160307333597000135551180000095485510202574\"

Obrigada a todos que responderam!